# Google errorprone java compiler - Bugs during maven build: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: pid

Tags: java, lombok, errorprone

I have added the following to the pom file:

```
<!-- Source: http://errorprone.info/docs/installation -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>javac-with-errorprone</compilerId>
                <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                <!-- maven-compiler-plugin defaults to targeting Java 5, but our javac
                     only supports >=6 -->
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac-errorprone</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- override plexus-compiler-javac-errorprone's dependency on
                     Error Prone with the latest version -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
                    <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Which during maven clean install leads to:

```
An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: pid
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.packageDeclaration(JavacAST.java:107)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.<init>(JavacAST.java:81)
    at lombok.javac.JavacTransformer.transform(JavacTransformer.java:67)
    at lombok.javac.apt.Processor.process(Processor.java:250)
    at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor$JavacDescriptor.process(AnnotationProcessor.java:115)
    at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessor.java:165)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:801)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:713)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$2000(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1021)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1141)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:833)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:249)
    at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneCompiler.run(ErrorProneCompiler.java:220)
    at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneCompiler.run(ErrorProneCompiler.java:158)
    at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneCompiler.compile(ErrorProneCompiler.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.errorprone.JavacCompilerWithErrorProne$CompilerInvoker.compile(JavacCompilerWithErrorProne.java:219)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.errorprone.JavacCompilerWithErrorProne.performCompile(JavacCompilerWithErrorProne.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:825)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

...

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile
>   (default-compile) on project Core: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile
>   (default-compile) on project Core: Compilation failure    at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException:
>   Compilation failure   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:915)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     ... 19 more [ERROR]

Hmm.. I notice just now that it is comlaining with regards to a lombok related AST stuff.

**Does errorprone and lombok not work well together?**

**What can I do to resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, solved it by using Java 8 to compile (turned out that my `JAVA_HOME` was pointing to a Java 9 version).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18781139)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @smttsp. I know that this is not exactly an answer, but I still wanted to share my experience in case it could help somebody. Ideally my "answer" would have been a comment. Alas, I don't have enough reputation to comment an answer that is not mine.

Comment: @AhmadShahwan Thanks, maybe now I can retry. Did you use lombok?

Comment: Any time @momomo, hope this helped. Yes I was using lombok, more precisely, I was compiling this wildfly swarm [example](https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-examples/tree/master/jaxrs/jaxrs-cdi).

Answer (score 4):

They indeed do not work well together, because of compiler.

[Error-prone dev comments (Jun, 26, 2015)](https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/347#issuecomment-115812988):

> We made the decision to pin Error Prone to a specific version of javac because Error Prone relies on compiler internals, and supporting multiple versions of javac was difficult and hard to validate, because we use only one version of javac internally.

[Lombok dev comment (Oct, 12, 2015)](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/942#issuecomment-147311154):

> I'm afraid Java 9 support is not going to be fixed in a few days.

It looks like all releases of errorprone starting with 2.0 do use javac9, thus making it not possible to workaround, although you may try previous versions of errorprone.

Comment: Update for new visitors (2017). Lombok now supports `javac9`. If you have this issue now, it is for other reasons.

Comment: @momomo It has other issues now that sometimes make it not work too well, but this answer is no longer the issue.